# Create MySQL Database in Python using the %s operator

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Trying to create a database where the name is given through the %s operator.

```
import mysql.connector, MySQLdb
db_name='SomeString'

#create connection to mysql
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root")

#init cursor
mycursor=mydb.cursor()

#create database
mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE (%s)", (db_name))
```

This is the error msg:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(%s)' at line 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You don't need to enclose the `%s` in brackets. This is what is causing the syntax error. You don't need them around `db_name` either.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I have tried it without the brackets as such:

mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE %s", db_name). The same error appears :/

Comment: Sorry, was being a bit dim! See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are intending the value of `db_name` to be inserted instead of the `%s`, like a placeholder in `C`. This doesn't work as you have found out. Instead, you could do something like:

```
create_statement = "CREATE DATABASE {:s}".format(db_name)
mycursor.execute(create_statement)
```

Doing it this way will allow you to use the technique in more complex situations where there is more SQL after the value you are trying to substitute.

Comment: why you wrote :s?  only {} would be enough i guess.