# Create MySQL Table Column in Python using the %s operator

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Similar to Brunonono in [Create MySQL Database in Python using the %s operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726140/create-mysql-database-in-python-using-the-s-operator?noredirect=1#comment100012229_56726140) (even using the same packages) I'm trying to add columns from an excel table to a mysql table using the %s operator in Python. The error is the same:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s %s)' at line 1
```

## The code is as follows

```
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root")

#init cursor
mycursor=mydb.cursor()

column_title="ID"
cell_type="INT(10)"

mycursor.execute("ALTER TABLE Test ADD (%s %s)"),(column_title, cell_type)
```

Sadly, I wouldn't know how to apply the solution provided in the post above, where

```
mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE (%s)", (db_name))
```

was replaced with

```
create_statement = "CREATE DATABASE {:s}".format(db_name)
mycursor.execute(create_statement)
```

Comment: replace `(db_name)` with `(db_name,)`

Comment: Play around with "format" in a Python interactive shell to get a feeling how it works. And of course read the docs.

Comment: the part with db_name is referencing another post. It is not actually part of my problem. My error occurs at the line mycursor.execute("ALTER TABLE Test ADD (%s %s)"),(column_title, cell_type)

Comment: @MichaelButscher I assume that means that my problem is equally solvable using this method? :) Thats great

Comment: You can't substitute literals like column names, table names or types using query parameters. You have to use string formatting for this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312737/can-i-parameterize-the-table-name-in-a-prepared-statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mycursor.execute("ALTER TABLE Test ADD (%s %s)"),(column_title, cell_type)` is what you are doing currently

Instead do,

```py
mycursor.execute("ALTER TABLE Test ADD (%s %s)" % (column_title, cell_type))
```

Which would work unless I don't know MySQL syntax properly

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

mycursor.execute('ALTER TABLE Test ADD (?, ?)',(column_title, cell_type))

But this doesn't use the %s operator.

Sorry, this works for SQLite and not MySQL.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: this gives the error: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement. Thanks tho :)